# Какой поисковый движок выбрать для сайта на Django?

Tags: django, поиск

Движок должен иметь доступ к БД на MySQL, т.к. некоторый контент загружается только по ajax-запросу пользователей. Пока рассматриваю Haystack, у кого есть опыт работы с ним?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использовал Haystack для организации поиска товара в интернет-магазине. Движок брал Whoosh. Менее требовательный к ресурсам и работает не как отдельный процесс. Все работало великолепно.

Если есть время и средста настроить качественный поиск - советую Sphinx, Sorl, или же Elasticsearch.

Но на практике из этих трех я использовал только Sphinx. И то, из PHP..

Answer (score 2):

[Один из лучших поисковых движков, Sphinx.](http://sphinxsearch.com/)